# Create drop down list to populate foreign key fields

Tags: oracle10g

i am new to oracle 10g. I am using it to build some forms. I have created all the tables in sql+ and i have designed my forms. I am having a problem with the foreign key fields in the form.

I have a table named class, class has 4 foreign keys which are represented on the class form

1. R_ID which is the primary key of a table called ROOM
2. E_ID which the primary key of a table called EXAM
3. T_ID which is the primary key of a table called TERM
4. SUB_ID which is the primary key of a table called SUBJECT

In the class form i want the user to be able to create or update a record of a class. For user friendliness i want when they put the cursor on any one of the foreign key field to enter its value, I want the corresponding NAME  from the parent table to be displayed as a drop down list instead/as well as  the numerical foreign key value. The user's choice would populate the foreign key field of the class table so

IF R_ID = RM001 and the name of that room in the parent table is Chemistry LAB. I want the user to see chemistry lab and choose that but it populates the class table in the database as RM001

I have created all my navigation manually via buttons, this is the last thing i have to do and im stumped. I want the user to be able to click the field and the drop down list automatically appears.

Any ideas? thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for people you are seeking this information

Use the list of values (lov) wizard.
Build query in the wizard by selecting the attributes of the table you want( the parent table of the foreign key)
Set the return value as the foreign key in the child table
Assign a button to execute the lov created

This works